# Why can't yarn.lock found in my Docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg

I am run a single Node.js script like so: `docker run -it --rm -u node --name build_container -v $(pwd):/home/node/app -w "/home/node/app" node:lts bash -c "yarn install --no-cache --frozen-lockfile"`.

However, the script log shows the displays `info No lockfile found`, and, what is even weirder, a message that says a **package-lock.json** was found. However, the work directory has no **package-lock**.

[image]

Are there any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: well its sayiing that it was added automatically.. but also what is the structure of the project?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using your own `Dockerfile` to build your image - and then run it inside the build - like so:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:12-alpine

# Create work directory
RUN mkdir -p /express
WORKDIR /express

# Bundle app sources
COPY . .

# Build app
RUN yarn install --prod --frozen-lockfile && yarn run build

EXPOSE 3000

# Set default NODE_ENV to production
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENTRYPOINT [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

`.dockerignore`

```
node_modules
build
dist
config
docs
*.log
.git
.vscode
```

And then build the image:
`docker build -t <your image name> -f <Dockerfile (if omitted uses local folder .Dockerfile> <path to code your code>`

Once built, run it as you would a normal image - as everything is already in.